# Why image is not showed on JSP page

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets

I'm a bit lost with following scenario:

1. user upload image - upload.jsp (multipart/form-data)
2. servlet do all dirty job (save image, get name, save name, redirect to display.jsp)
3. on the display.jsp, just uploaded image should be presented

Unfortunately the display.jsp page is empty. When I look at source page under firefox, everything seems to be fine, valid link to the image is provided.

```
<img src="/UploadTest/avatar/55_445194458350473498.png" border=0 width="48px" height="48px"/>
```

But under Media info I can see some weird infos:

```
Location:   http://localhost:8084/UploadTest/avatar/55_445194458350473498.png
Type:       text/html
Size:       Unknown (not cached)
Dimensions: 0px x 0px (scaled to 0px x 16px)
```

Here is code used for uploading, processing and displaying picture:

**upload.jsp**

```
<form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">File:</label>
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Upload.java**

(The MultipartMap servlet belongs to BalusC, http://balusc.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html)

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import test.MultipartMap;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/Users/Thomas/NetBeansProjects/UploadTest/web/Upload" })
@MultipartConfig(location = "/Users/Thomas/NetBeansProjects/UploadTest/web/avatar", maxFileSize = 10485760L) // 10MB.
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {  
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {

    MultipartMap map = new MultipartMap(request, this);

    File file = map.getFile("file");

    String filename = file.getName();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("filename", filename);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/display.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**display.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar/${filename}" border=0 width="48px" height="48px"/>
      <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I replace, in display.jsp, ${filename} with static name of the particular image uploaded before, there is no problem with displaying so I suppose the images are processed correctly just something is missing on forward side?

By the way: when debugger is active everything is OK but when switch off the problem is back.

Cheers,

Thomas

Comment: use `<img src="avatar/${filename}" />`. No need to take contextpath

Comment: In your annotation, you have location = "/Users/Thomas/NetBeansProjects/UploadTest/web/avatar".  But in your link you have src="/UploadTest/avatar/55_445194458350473498.png". Is that a typo? Is the avatar folder in the web folder?

Comment: @rickz yes, the avatar folder is in the web folder.

Comment: Ok, change link in display.jsp to <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/web/avatar/${filename}"

Comment: @rickz This is not good location and as I said before there is no problem with location of the file, src tag point to the proper image. The question is why the image is text/html type?

Comment: I am confused. Your number 3 in your question states that you wanted to display the uploaded image. So shouldn't the location attribute in the annotation be the same as the src attribute in img tag?

Answer (score 0):

Good explanation. I go through your problem and create sample of it. I have same problem as you face. 
The solution is that put below line in display.jsp file:

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

I think the problem with EL and page is not able to evaluate correctly.
Below is code:
upload.jsp and upload.java is same as yours.

display.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/${filename}" border=0 width="48px" height="48px" alt="Image Not found"/>
      <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this will work for you also

Thank you

Comment: Thank you bud, but problem is somewhere else. I changed a bit upload.jsp to be sure but result is the same. In the upload.jsp added 2 lines: 
String filename1 = file.getName();
String filename2 = "55_4518625602858925634.png"; 

in Display.jsp: 
<img src="/avatar/${filename1}"/>
<img src="/avatar/${filename2}"/>

The ${filename2} is showed but not ${filemame1

Answer (score -1):

Can you view the uploaded image in a pic viewer?

Is the file size correct and the data not corrupted?

Is your server running on port 8084?

I wonder why you get type text/html when it should be image/png.

Comment: The images before upload and after upload are perfectly correct. I can see them in the browser but only if real name is given not ${filename} variable.

Comment: What debugger do you use? Do you use Apache Tomcat?

Comment: @MagnusStrand: is it your answer? I only see some comments here

Comment: @codeMaker: sorry, I am not allowed to make comments yet [why-cant-i-comment-on-this-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9701/why-cant-i-comment-on-this-answer)